# How to clear app cache programmatically on Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

As I have been developing app using Flutter. I came to find that app is heavy in size plus it is using a lot of space as app data and app cache. Is there any way to clear app cache programmatically?

Edit: my app's size in release mode is about 7mb and app data is about 11mb.
My app opens one site within app and it also streams online radio so it's app data goes on increasing

Comment: What is the size of the apk and the app data?

Comment: in release mode its 7.5mb and app data minimum is 11mb and it goes on increasing

Comment: 7.5 MB is an expected size. Flutter has to provide many heavy files underneath the platform.

Comment: but my problem is how to clear app cache only

Answer (score 21):

You can get the temp folder, and delete files in it.

```
var appDir = (await getTemporaryDirectory()).path;
new Directory(appDir).delete(recursive: true);
```

Comment: Getting this error with this code, any ideas? Unhandled Exception: FileSystemException: Deletion failed, path = '/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/.../Library/Caches' (OS Error: Operation not permitted, errno = 1).  - ran on iOS

Comment: I didn't test on ios, cause I don't have a mac.

Comment: i don't know and i was looking for the same solution as you but i think this is because of the permissions which can be solved by going to Android Manifest and Add file access permissions because right now your app doesn't have the permission to edit or delete files from the user's storage

Comment: @RYOK, I have the same problem like this case, would you like to give example how to allow permission to edit or delete files from the user's storage ?

Comment: @LukeStanyer did you find any solution of this " Unhandled Exception: FileSystemException: Deletion failed, path = '/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/.../Library/Caches' (OS Error: Operation not permitted, errno = 1)",  I am having the same issue and couldn't find any solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @AshishBharwal This was a while ago now, but I think it was because I was trying to delete a directory that didn't exist. So I called it within an if dir.exists(); statement.

Answer (score 10):

You can also use use [flutter_cache_manager](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_cache_manager) to delete or remove your app's cache programatically.

After installing `flutter_cache_manager` , use this :

```
await DefaultCacheManager().emptyCache();
```

Answer (score 6):

it's working you just have to refresh your app after this.

```
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

  Future<void> _deleteCacheDir() async {
    var tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();

    if (tempDir.existsSync()) {
      tempDir.deleteSync(recursive: true);
    }
  }

  Future<void> _deleteAppDir() async {
    var appDocDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();

    if (appDocDir.existsSync()) {
      appDocDir.deleteSync(recursive: true);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

Note on Vincent's answer.

Try to avoid clearing the device's temporary folder. It'll be saver to clear the app it's cache folder like:

```
var appDir = (await getTemporaryDirectory()).path + '/<package_name>';
new Directory(appDir).delete(recursive: true);
```

Comment: by package_name, what are you referring to?  I wouldn't think Bundle ID, Apple ID? UUID?

Comment: @jbryanh it's the Bundle ID.

Answer (score 2):

You Can Easily Remove cache.

```
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
Future<void> _deleteCacheDir() async {
final cacheDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
if (cacheDir.existsSync()) {
cacheDir.deleteSync(recursive: true);}}
final appDir = await getApplicationSupportDirectory();
if (appDir.existsSync()) {
appDir.deleteSync(recursive: true);}}
```