# What is the flutter command to clear app data?

Tags: flutter, command-line-interface

Sometimes we need to run app by clearing app data and cache. It is a hassle to do it manually every time going to setting screens.I saw maximum stack-overflow answers recommending it [programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53296899/how-to-clear-app-cache-programmatically-on-flutter) but I don't need it. Is there any **flutter command** or **plugin** to do that?

Answer (score 1):

There is actually no flutter command to clear app data.

However, you could use prelaunch tasks to run shell command before launching your app.

You must have **adb** command in your environment PATH variable for Android apps

For example, in VsCode, you can add a task in the `tasks.json` file like this :

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "clear app data",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "adb shell pm clear com.package.app || true;xcrun simctl uninstall booted com.package.app",
            "problemMatcher": []
        }
    ]
}
```

Then, add the **preLaunchTask** in your `launch.json` file like this :

```
{
  // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
  // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
  // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "my_app",
      "request": "launch",
      "type": "dart",
      "program": "lib/main.dart",
      "preLaunchTask": "clear app data",
    }
  ]
}
```

I don't know how to do this in IntelliJ but I'm sure you can do the same thing